# MySql - Restrict calculations allowed in SELECT clause of query

Tags: mysql, sql, security, select, sql-injection

In mysql (version 5.6) I can have formula/calculations in my `SELECT` clause.

e.g.

```
SELECT (a*2) as x, (b+2) as y, sum(...) from table_name;
```

I can also pass the calculations dynamically. The problem is that I can pass any formula.  Is there a way I can restrict to what can be put in `SELECT` clause?  This may be exploited in Injection attacks.

EDIT:  I can put something like:

```
SELECT @@version, @@hostname, (a*2) as x, (b+2) as y, sum(...) from table_name;
```

This would expose my DB version and hostname.

Comment: Editing the question.

Comment: Why are you allowing unrestricted access to your database in the first place?

Comment: Users can pass formulae to a Select statement.  I don't think version and hostname qualify as unrestricted access.

Comment: You have users. You should be able to trust those users

Comment: The users are end users, who may be malicious often times.

Comment: You can define views and restrict the access only to those views.

Comment: I still don't understand how or why these kinds of users have this kind of access to your database. Normally, users access the database through some sort of application layer (php served over html is a common approach). The place to prevent injection would be in that application layer.

Comment: We use an HTTP Wrapper over MySql database.  By pre-configuring queries against an endpoint, and passing query parameters to the sql, we are able to use DB over HTTP.

Comment: So just restrict the 'query parameters'

Comment: There is no place to restrict query parameters.  On the UI, it may be done, but a malicious user can always 'Copy as Curl' and modify the parameters.  Server side there is this generic framework that is not a middle tier, but an HTTP Wrapper over the DB.

Comment: You need some sort of "middle tier" in the web server that does some validation and accept only valid queries. But in general, allowing the user to construct the query directly is a very dangerous thing to do, as they can submit virtually anything, like subqueries, system commands, even exploit some injection technique to escape the `SELECT` and gain control of the server. DoS and data exfiltration are very likely threats here.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, Using a view would not help. Any query could pass expressions in the select-list when querying a view, as easily as when querying a base table.

Answer (score 1):

The closes thing to what you probably have in mind is something called prepared statements.  Statements can prevent a malicious user from injecting SQL via a literal value in a SQL query.  But, statements  do not allow the columns themselves to be parameters.

The only safe way I can think of here is that you select the columns all of whose values are needed in the user defined formula.  Then, you return those columns/variables to the app layer, and compute the formula there.  If you try to build the formula in SQL with input from the user, e.g. from the UI, then you run the risk of being injected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Tim.  The issue here is that I don't have an app layer involved.  Is there any way in the query itself?

Comment: Off the top of my head, you could create a table containing formula fragments. The user may choose which fragments make it into the final formula.  Whatever you use, you can't let the user directly control the text going into the query.

Comment: Thanks Tim.  This is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTTP wrapper sounds like it's vulnerable by design.

If you allow untrusted input to be executed as part of your SQL queries, this is the definition of SQL injection.

The common advice for preventing SQL injection is to use query parameters. This is great if the dynamic part of the query is the equivalent of a constant value (like a quoted string value, a date, or a numeric literal), but it doesn't work for other things you might want in a query, like a column name, or like an expression as you're doing.

What @TimBiegeleisen describes is sometimes called *whitelisting*.

In a whitelisting approach, the user cannot send literal expressions. They *choose* SQL expressions, but they can only choose from a set of predefined expressions that you control in your app.

This is SQL injection:

```
http://example.com/query?expr=(a*2) as x
```

This is whitelisting:

```
http://example.com/query?expr=1
```

Where "1" is hard-coded to choose the 1st in your set of approved expressions. You could use a `case` statement, or an array, or something like that.

This works as a whitelist because if the user tries to send an expr id that doesn't correspond to one of the keys in your `case` statement or expression array, then your app would either do nothing, or return an error message.

```
http://example.com/query?expr=(select password from users)
```

could return:

```
HTTP Status 400 Bad Request
```

This does require you to have some more robust app layer. You would have to write the code to do the mapping of expression id's to the full expression.

Comment: Thanks @Bill Karwin.  Very helpful insight!